# How to check if a BindableProperty is being used?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control where I create different `BindableProperties`. Is there a way to check if a `BindableProperty` is being used?

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ExampleItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ExampleItemSource", typeof(IList), typeof(Editor));

public IList ExampleItemSource{
  get {
    return (IList) GetValue(ExampleItemSourceProperty );
  }
  set {
    SetValue(ExampleItemSourceProperty , value);
  }
}

if (ExampleItemSourceProperty == null) {
  //do something

} else {

  //do something

}
```

Answer (score 1):

We could implement it by the event **propertyChanged** of the BindableProperty .

A static property-changed callback method can be registered with a bindable property by specifying the **propertyChanged** parameter for the `BindableProperty.Create` method. The specified callback method will be invoked when the value of the bindable property changes.

```
   public static readonly BindableProperty ExampleItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ExampleItemSource", typeof(IList), typeof(Editor), propertyChanged: OnExampleItemChanged);

    static void OnExampleItemChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        // this method will been called when we binding this property and set the value.
        var editor = bindable as Editor;

        if(newValue !=null)
        {
             //...
            ObservableCollection<Example> ExampleList = new ObservableCollection<Example>(); 
            editor.collectionView.ItemsSource = ExampleList; 
        }

        else
        {
            //...
        }

    }
```

Comment: I need to use the x:Name of a control in the if and else but if its not in the constructor I can't use it. How can I do this?

Comment: Why can't use it  if its not in the constructor ?

Comment: When I add this inside the if:   ObservableCollection<Example> ExampleList = new ObservableCollection<Example>();
                collectionView.ItemsSource = ExampleList;   collectionView get an error. Error: "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property..."

Comment: It doesn't work for me at all. My idea is that if the binding is in use, the newValue! = null does nothing, but if the binding is not used, that is, that ExampleItemSource property is not used, use that ItemSource. from the else but when I remove the binding, it doesn't add anything to the list, that else doesn't work.

Comment: You could set a default value of ItemSource .

Comment: You left the chat :/